# Django Rest Framework - Downloading files on server

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am writing an API that allows the client to post a link to a file, and then I want to download the file and store it as a `FileField` on one of my models. Here is the code I have so far:

**Serializer:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.core.files import File
from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('url')

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        validated = dict()

        url = data.get('url')

        # do url validation here

        # download the file to local disk

        validated['file'] = File(open('path/to/downloaded/file'))
        validated['url'] = url

        return validated
```

**Model:**

```
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
```

For the view, I use a generic `ListCreateAPIView`.

There are two main problems, first is that with my current implementation, I end up with two copies of the file because I download it to some location on disk first, and then later when the `FileField` is stored into the database it copies the file again to the `files/` folder. Is there some way to avoid this? Secondly, how can I download the file asynchronously yet still be able to add the `FileField` attribute on the model after the download has completed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way of doing the same thing will be to create Your own `serializer field`

```
from django.core.validators import URLValidator
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

from rest_framework import serializers

from urllib.request import urlretrieve

class FileUrlField(serializers.FileField):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            URLValidator()(data)
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid Url')

        # download the contents from the URL
        file, http_message = urlretrieve(data)
        file = File(open(file, 'rb'))
        return super(FileUrlField, self).to_internal_value(ContentFile(file.read(), name=file.name))
```

and then Use it in your `serializer`

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file = FileUrlField()
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

However i am Not tested it but should work.